# How can I record the number of times something happens over several files?

Tags: python, logging

I'm looking to keep a summary of both the number of times a specific thing happens and when something very important arises. I'll give an example...

My code establishes a ssh connection and runs commands. An exception is raised and handled every time the script loses connection to the ssh server. Let's say this type of exception is handled in different ways across multiple files. How can I keep a record of the number of times this is handled? This is not specific to exceptions. If, for example, I run a command and get a certain response back, I want to make note that this occurred. I need all of this to be logged (I already know how to set up the logger) when the script ends.

The reason for doing this is because my script logs a large amount of information and I want to be able to have a quick summary of important things that happened at the end of the log file.

tldr; How can I keep a record of the number of times something occurs / when something occurs across multiple files so I can log it when the script ends?

Comment: Are you doing this at logging time, or looking through the log file ex post facto?

Comment: I was thinking of doing it at logging time.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of your logging messages? A useful solution will most likely need to unambiguously identify events in your logs.

Comment: logger.error('Connection Lost. Reconnecting.') Very simple. So let's say I want to be able to record the number of times I lose connection to the ssh server while my script is executing.

Comment: Right now I just have a dictionary that I import into every file where I add another key if something happens or increase the value of a key if I'm keeping track of the number of times it occurs. And then log it all at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by `multiple files` you mean you have multiple separate scripts running and you want to log some consolidated summary of events occurring in all those scripts.

If you have a single script it is easy to do by maintaining a dict and dumping it to a log file or may be overwrite a single summary file, for multiple scripts you can run a *separate logging server* , which is used by all scripts for logging or at-least to add and dump summary info, alternatively you can use a common *database with table locking*

Comment: It's just one script and I am currently using a dictionary to maintain the summary but I was just wondering if this was the best way to be doing it or is there a better way?

Comment: i will say that is the best way, simple is better, just make a common function or class to update and dump the data

Answer (score 1):

Try subclassing `logging.Handler` and overriding the `handle` or `emit` method to check the message being sent and increment a counter somewhere as appropriate, and then adding this handler to your application's root logger like so:

```
import logging
counter = 0
class CounterHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        global counter
        if record.msg == "Connection lost. Reconnecting.":
            counter += 1

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.addHandler(CounterHandler())
```

You can expand on this to make it more general or robust, but this is one way to accomplish what you're looking for.